# epstopdf auto implementation in xelatex

Tags: xetex

I am using `xelatex` compailation. epstopdf package is not supported in xelatex. So I am using below mentioned option

```
\immediate\write18{epstopdf fpubh-03-00040-g001.eps}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centerline{\includegraphics{fpubh-03-00040-g001.pdf}}
\caption{\textbf{\boldmath Building blocks of CCCs}.\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure*}
```

My current process is occured lot of manual works.

My requirement is that i should not change the eps format. But i need output in pdf format without changing the below command. How to execute epstopdf logic without manual interaction in xelatex?

```
\centerline{\includegraphics{fpubh-03-00040-g001.eps}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\title{Dynamic coverage control in unicycle multi-robot networks under anisotropic sensing}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
The Centers for Disease Prevention and Control's (CDC) National Comprehensive Cancer Control Program (NCCPC) fund 65 awardees (states, territories, Pacific Island jurisdictions, and tribes/tribal organizations) in 69 Comprehensive Cancer Control (CCC) programs to develop and implement CCC plans via CCC coalitions, alliances, or consortia of program stakeholders. CCC is a process through which communities and partner organizations pool resources to reduce the burden of cancer by reducing cancer risk, finding cancers earlier, improving treatments, increasing the number of people who survive cancer, and improving the quality of life for cancer survivors. CCC plans are intended to guide community and state-wide activities in cancer prevention and control in states, territories, tribes and tribal organizations, and Pacific Island jurisdictions. The plans are intended to be data-driven, evidence-based blueprints for action, and generally cover a 5-year timeframe. In the fifth year, different processes are used to revise and update CCC plans. CCC plans serve as written documentation of the burden of cancer and offer blueprints for coordinated action~--~ideally laying out measurable objectives and specifying which organizations will be responsible for supporting specific strategies to meet those objectives.

\immediate\write18{epstopdf fpubh-03-00040-g001.eps}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centerline{\includegraphics{fpubh-03-00040-g001.pdf}}
\caption{\textbf{\boldmath Building blocks of CCCs}.\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure*}

Chief among these building blocks are community capacity and sustainability, two constructs considered as essential for achieving long-term success in designing, implementing, and disseminating cancer-related public health practices and policies. Despite their importance, little is known about the extent to which community capacity building and sustainability constructs are addressed in current cancer control plans. The purpose of this article is to offer a review of state plans, including the District of Columbia, and document where and in what manner these two constructs are explicitly addressed. Based on a review of select state plans, recommendations are offered that are designed to assist states to more effectively address community capacity building and sustainability as plans are updated and revised.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use `\includegraphics{fpubh-03-00040-g001}` with no extension  then use a simple loop at your command line to make a zzz.pdf file for each zzz.eps and tex will just load whichever it needs. With `\write18` as above you are converting all the eps files everytime you run the file through latex, which is massively inefficient.

Comment: You can use EPS files in XeTeX, why do you want to convert to PDF?

Comment: @Operdiek If i am using the eps, the file size is increasing 2x. This is the reason i will try to use the epstopdf concept

Comment: @casrlisle epstopdf package is using to convert epstopdf. The same concept i implement in xelatex. But the package is not supported. If you have any alternative automated macros for this logic.

Comment: @Vetri but only converts them once, but I'd just use the suggestion above if you want to include pdf.